# CPU overheating (Acer 4730z + Ubuntu 12.10)

Tags: 12.10, cpu, overheating, temperature

After using the pre-installed Windows Vista on my Acer Aspire 4730z for over 4 years, I decided to switch to Ubuntu. I installed a brand new SSD with Ubuntu 12.04, which I later upgraded to 12.10. Everything works fine, except for the fact that the CPU gets very hot. This problem exists under 12.04 and 12.10. It did not exist under Windows Vista.

-Idle temperature is around 55 degrees Celcius (@ about 2-3% CPU usage)
-When watching 1080p video (CPU usage around 50%) it can get up to 90 degrees Celcius

My only guess is that it might have something to do with the integrated graphics (If I check under system > details, it says "Graphics: Unknown").

Other than that, I don't have a clue. Any ideas?

Some quick specs:
Intel® Pentium® dual-core mobile processor T3200 (1 MB L2 cache, 2.0 GHz, 667 MHz FSB, 35 W), supporting Intel® 64 architecture
Mobile Intel® GL40 Express Chipset
Mobile Intel® GL40 Express Chipset with integrated 3D graphics, featuring Intel® Graphics Media Accelerator 4500M (Intel® GMA 4500M) with up to 1759 MB of Intel® Dynamic Video Memory

Answer (score 0):

90° C is high, but is still within range.  According to [Intel](http://ark.intel.com/products/37160/Intel-Pentium-Processor-T3200-1M-Cache-2_00-GHz-667-MHz-FSB-Socket-P) you processor is rated at 100° C.

[image]

Now the fact that you said the you've been running window for 4 years, I'm sure that the unit has accumulated its share from dust.  My suggestion try to clean the CPU fan with some compressed air, I think it will help.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this on a couple of laptops. Depending on how the BIOS is set up, the fans may only "kick in" if the temperature gets too high. If "too high" was determined by Windows to be lower that the BIOS "too high" then when switching to ubuntu you may find the fans don't run as much. I would see if there's any relevant BIOS settings on your machine.

There are also a number of ubuntu programs for automatically increasing the fan speed. As another post points out, you're below the maximum temperature but running a CPU at cooler temperatures will decrease your failure rate.

Answer (score 0):

Well I removed as much dust as possible (especially from the CPU fan area) and that made the temperature drop about 10 degrees. The temperature range is now about 45-80 degrees Celcius. Still a bit higher than when I was using Windows, but I'm quite happy with the results. I might renew the thermal paste on the CPU as well, just to see if this further decreases the temperature.

The fan DOES seem to behave very different under Ubuntu than it did under Windows. I might have to look into that as well.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how you can solve this but I recommend you to take some precautions like:

You need to know or be aware when your pc cpu is getting very hot, if I were you I used a program to handle this, because the temperature can kill your cpu, it affects badly on performance and its life..

I wrote a script about this I called it [CPU Temperature Alarm System.](http://eeecoder.blogspot.com/2013/07/cpu-scaklk-alarm-sistemi.html)

You may wanna see it. I hope it helps..